# How to parse partial link in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I am trying to show an image into my table cell view from an API. But it has given a partial link there, as a result, I am getting NSURL connection error code -1002.

Here is my API link: https://api.opendota.com/api/heroStats

I am trying to parse "icon" among them:
"img": "/apps/dota2/images/heroes/antimage_full.png?",
"icon": "/apps/dota2/images/heroes/antimage_icon.png",

My code:
// Generating imageview

```
if let imageURL = URL(string: heroes[indexPath.row].icon){
    print (imageURL)
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        let data = try? Data (contentsOf: imageURL)
        if let data = data {
            let image = UIImage(data: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell.charIcon.image = image
            } //end of 2nd dispatch
        }//end of if
    }//end of 1st dispatch
}// end of imageURL
```

How can I solve this problem? Any easy way for swift 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the url components of your api link and use your icon "partial link" to set the path property of the URL components. After that you just need to get the resulting url of the url components:

```
let apiLink = "https://api.opendota.com/api/heroStats"
let apiURL = URL(string: apiLink)!
if var urlComponents = URLComponents(url: apiURL, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false) {
    let iconString = "/apps/dota2/images/heroes/antimage_icon.png"
    urlComponents.path = iconString
    if let iconURL = urlComponents.url {
        print(iconURL.absoluteString)
    }
}
```

---

This will print

> https://api.opendota.com/apps/dota2/images/heroes/antimage_icon.png

---

---

You can create a custom method to return a new URL based on the new path string as follow:

```
extension URL {
    var urlComponents: URLComponents? {
        return URLComponents(url: self, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)
    }
    func bySettingNew(path: String) -> URL? {
        guard var urlComponents = urlComponents else { return nil }
        urlComponents.path = path
        return urlComponents.url
    }
}
```

---

```
let apiLink = "https://api.opendota.com/api/heroStats"
let apiURL = URL(string: apiLink)!
let iconString = "/apps/dota2/images/heroes/antimage_icon.png"

if let iconURL = apiURL.bySettingNew(path: iconString) {
    print(iconURL.absoluteString)
}
```

---

---

You can also add this helper to your project to make it easier for you to download an image asynchronously into your image view:

```
extension UIImageView {
    func downloaded(from url: URL, contentMode mode: UIView.ContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard
                let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
                let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
                let data = data, error == nil,
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async() { [weak self] in
                self?.contentMode = mode
                self?.image = image
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

---

```
if let imageURL = apiURL.bySettingNew(path: heroes[indexPath.row].icon) {
    cell.charIcon.downloaded(from: imageURL)
}
```